Large thread-local struct causes segmentation faults
I'm working on a larger C-codebase and their I wanted to use a relatively large thread-local struct. It can be reduced to something like this:
typedef struct {
    char data[1024 * 1024 * 2];
} TheData;

static __thread TheData my_data = {};

If I use small struct-sizes, then everything works well. However, if I use larger ones, then at some point I get segfaults at very random locations in the application. It took me quite some time to figure this out, but finally I realized that it only depends on this thread-local struct. gcc does not produce any warning at all and as well ASAN and valgrind did not show anything.
My system: I use Linux with gcc 13.
Is there any limit for thread-local objects? Why? And is it possible to make compilers etc. warn if such a limit is hit?
Thanks a lot

Hwo are you spawning threads? What operating system are you using? If you are using linux, then we have https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_getattr_default_np.c#L31 and https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/nptl-init.c#L404 .

Thanks:)
Yeah, I use Linux with gcc. And yep, I spawn threads.

There is a rather low limit, and it is not known to the compiler so it cannot warn you.
Much better to allocate a struct using malloc. That is the least limited allocation, and it doesn’t tie your memory allocation to a thread, so the same thread can handle different “TheData” structs.
Why is the limit low? Because the compiler doesn’t know whether you will have two threads or 10,000 so it doesn’t know how much threadlocal storage per thread you can afford.

Is there actually a way to get this limit at runtime? Or how is it defined?
